# Set Unity TextMesh Pro width via script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I adjust the TextMesh Pro container width/ height in Unity via script (C#)?

I've tried getting the TextContainer component to set .width, but either that's deprecated or I'm doing it wrong, but the TextContainer is null. I've also tried directly setting .width on the TextMeshPro component but that doesn't work either. Thanks!

Comment: can you show the code you tried?

Comment: did you try to instead set `tmpText.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(desiredWidth, desiredHeihgt);`?

Answer (score 2):

sizeDelta gives you access to change width and height. I have just tried to make sure and it works.`

`[SerializeField] private RectTransform _textRectTransform;`

`_textRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(_textRectTransform.sizeDelta.x * 2, _textRectTransform.sizeDelta.y * 2);`

Comment: Thank you, that works great! I seem to have two fitting answers now, one here and one in the comments, Hugo's comment answer above also makes the GetComponent part very clear.